# White pages when using https (wordpress)

Tags: wordpress, https

For some reason I keep getting white pages when loading my website, it started happening since I have added an SSL Certificate and forced HTTPS redirection to the whole site, I have also changed the wordpress URL to HTTPS to force SSL as well.

Is there any reason this would happen?

I did try searching but could only find white screen of death issues but this only happens every now and again (around every 5-10 page loads)

Comment: Did you try enabling the error log just in case?

Comment: Hello, the error log doesn't show anything, it just shows a white blank page and on internet explorer it shows as a 500 internal server error. Thanks for the comment.